# layout methods doesn't set the instance variable rails 3.2 onwards

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, layout, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actioncontroller

I am working on a rails app, which is getting upgraded from rails(3.0.9) to rails (3.2.22). I will try to demonstrate the problem through a demo rails app.

I created demo app's for different rails versions. I have something like this inside.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  layout :select_layout

  def select_layout
    @tmp = 'tmp variable'
    @layout = 'application'
  end
end
```

And accessing @tmp inside ***layouts/application.html.erb*** :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TwistageScopeIssue</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %> <br/>
    <%= @tmp %> <br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Values(@tmp) displays correctly('tmp variable') in : 3.0.x and 3.1.x .

Values(@tmp) gets set to ***nil*** : 3.2.x onwards

I am still looking into the rails source code to get some information, meanwhile any thoughts/idea's would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: It seems odd that you would be setting an instance variable in a method that chooses a layout. They probably removed it so as not to violate Curly's Law. Set it in a `before_filter`.

Comment: @DickieBoy Thanks!! I have already tried that work-around and it works fine. It miserably fails the existing test-cases though, hence i was looking for suggestions before i start fixing them. I am still trying to understand the changes in later version's of rails which causes this change.

Comment: Is there any other/better solution for this problem??